# Custom Permalink: /year/month/post-goes-here/?

Tags: permalinks

I'm experimenting with adjusting permalinks (for purely educational experimentation).

What would I need to place in the "Custom Permalink" option to get my post URLs in the form...

/year/month/post-title-goes-here/

Comment: This is actually one of the predefined options on the settings page.

Comment: @scribu: Did you downvote because of that? I understand its predefined. I'm looking deeper to see "How" its made.

Comment: Yes. You select the option and the field is populated with the value tnorthcutt mentioned. You need to ask a question for that? If you really want to see how it's made, dive into `wp-includes/rewrite.php`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`

Comment: Glad I could help!